# why java is unable to initialize a set object?

Tags: java

```
package generics_practice_test;
import java.util.Set;
public class Main {

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Set<String> set = new Set<String>();// set object cannot be initialized
    }
}
```

The set object cannot be initialized by Java but when I replace `Set` by `HashSet` and import the `java.util.HashSet` and use the code `Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>` then the code works. I want to please know why.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Set` is an interface and interfaces are abstract in nature, so you cannot instantiate it. You need to use an implementation class of `Set` interface such as `HashSet`:

Change this

```
    Set<String> set = new Set<String>();// set object cannot be initialized
```

to

```
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
```

Comment: I'd change the second statement's comment to "// set object can be initialized"

Answer (score 1):

[set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is an interface in java so you can not create object of it

Comment: Thanks Mr. SpringLearner i am truly grateful.

Answer (score 1):

[Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) is an `interface` in java, and you can't make Object of an interface in Java.

Instead of that, try using this :

```
Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(); //HashSet is a subclass of Set interface
```

*Note :* [Using an Interface as a Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/interfaceAsType.html)

Answer (score 0):

`Set` is an `interface`,you can't initialize it,You have to use  its concrete classes which are implementing it

```
java.util.EnumSet
  java.util.HashSet
    java.util.LinkedHashSet
    java.util.TreeSet
```